# for i in range why is this telling me there is a syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax

Is there some rule I am breaking that causes a syntax error on the `order_additems = [[order_item, order_qty]]` line

```
number_of_ordered_items = int(input('''How many items would you like to order? '''))
for i in range(number_of_ordered_items):
    order_item = input('''Enter the Product Name you would like to order: ''')
    order_qty = (input('''How many would you like to order?: ''')
    order_additems = [[order_item, order_qty]]
    writer = csv.writer(order_file)
    writer.writerows(order_additems)
```

Comment: unbalanced parentheses in `order_qty = (input('''How many would you like to order?: ''')`...

Comment: wow I can't believe I missed that thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra opening parenthesis on the previous line:

```
order_qty = (input('''How many would you like to order?: ''')
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra parenthesis when you define `order_qty`

```
number_of_ordered_items = int(input('''How many items would you like to order? '''))
for i in range(number_of_ordered_items):
    order_item = input('''Enter the Product Name you would like to order: ''')
    order_qty = input('''How many would you like to order?: ''')
    order_additems = [[order_item, order_qty]]
    writer = csv.writer(order_file)
    writer.writerows(order_additems)
```

Answer (score -1):

unmatched paranthesis on line 4 and you shouldn't be using `''' '''` in print statements as they are [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#:%7E:text=A%20docstring%20is%20a%20string,module%20should%20also%20have%20docstrings.) you shoud be using double quotes or single quotes instead.

Comment: `'''` and `"""` are multi-line strings (and not 'just' docstrings). they can be used anywhere.

Comment: I agree with you..but I think there's no need to use them In this case.